# Is SSH logging capabilities equivalent to su logging for private/public key authentication?

Tags: security, ssh, unix, authentication, logging

Here at work, we have a non-root shared login account on UNIX that is used to admin a particular application. The policy is to not allow direct logins to the shared account; you must login as yourself and use the "su" command to change over to the shared account. This is for logging/security purposes.

I've started using SSH public/private key authentication with an agent to allow me to enter my password once a day and let the agent forwarding eliminate the password prompts for the rest of the day. It is really nice.

However, some systems are locked down so I really have to use the "su" command to get to the shared account. Arg! Back to entering passwords all the time!

Is there enough info logged with SSH public/private key authentication such that I could have a reasonable chance of requesting a policy change to allow remote logins to a shared account if public/private keys are used?

I had an admin look in /var/log/secure and it just says that a public key was accepted for a user account from a particular IP address. It didn't say who's public key it was, or who's private key did the authentication.

Answer (score 13):

There are many levels of logging available through the `sshd_config` file. See the [man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd_config&sektion=5) and look for `LogLevel`. The default level is `INFO` but it's trivially easy to bump it up to `VERBOSE` or even one of the `DEBUG#` levels.

Additionally, you should explore [`sudo`](http://www.sudo.ws/) as an alternative to `su`. A full discussion of the benefits of `sudo` would be a question of its own. But I can say that with `sudo` you can tailor how often you have to enter your password, which commands may be run, etc., all controllable through the [sudoers](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/man/sudoers.html) config file.

Comment: Voted up for suggesting a sudo replacement.

Answer (score 6):

Another way would be to move `authorized_keys` outside of the user's scope (for example to `/etc/ssh/authorized_keys`) so that only sysadmins would control which public keys can be used to log to given accounts.

We used to change the `AuthorizedKeysFile` directive in `sshd_config` to something like the following.

```
AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/authorized_keys/%u
```

Then create and populate `/etc/ssh/authorized_keys` directory with files for each user that's supposed to be able to login, making sure `root` file is readable/writable only to root and other files readable by an appropriate user, like this:

```
-rw-------  1 root root    1,7K 2008-05-14 14:38 root
-rw-r-----  1 root john     224 2008-11-18 13:15 john
```

Each file contain a set of public keys that will be allowed to log into a given account. It is quite common for each user account there is a respective group as well.

Using public/private keys is a way better method for controlling remote user access. You don't have to change the password every month (you don't have to set it either), and don't have to change it just because an employee left your company just remove their public key; and of course with SSH options (`http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd&sektion=8#SSHRC`) you can fine-grain to what and from where a given user might have an access.

Answer (score 1):

SSH public/private key authentication is separate from the host authentication. You are out of luck here. You could request though that members of particular group be allowed to run certain administrative commands via `sudo` without password - like the example bellow allows users in the `secretaries` group to manage accounts:

```
# file: /etc/sudoers
...
%secretaries    ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/adduser, /usr/bin/rmuser   
...
```

Comment: Second this.. it is much, much easier to audit when you use SUDO.. you can see user joe typed "sudo appname -options" which is much simpler than seeing root typed "appname -options" and then have to go reconcile who all was logged in as root at that time.

Comment: OK, that helps. However, some of our tasks are to start and stop daemon processes. Will sudo allow us to run the "start" and "stop" scripts as the shared group username? (that is non-root) We want the processes to be owned by the shared  account username we setup.

Comment: Yes, the `-u` option lets you do that, see the manual http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/man/1.8.1/sudo.man.html